# Laravel custom deploy without composer, npm, git - With error 'invalid route action', but solved with some attemps

Tags: laravel, deployment

I'm having several issues with a custom first deploy for a **Laravel** project with **AdminLTE** and **Jetstream** and I'm unable to resolve them, even if after some attemps the application works, I don't understand why and where the issues arise and how to obtain a stable deploy.

Let me explain: the production server **has NO composer and npm and git installed** (and I can't install them), therefore I create a clean tar archive to upload on the server, and these are my step-by-step command sequence **on my local developer device**:

```
composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
npm install
npm run production
tar --transform='flags=r;s|.env.production|.env|' -czvf bin/archive/MYARCHIVE-VERSION.tar.gz --exclude='.git' --exclude='.idea' --exclude='.editorconfig' --exclude='.env' --exclude='.env.example' --exclude='.gitattributes' --exclude='.gitignore' --exclude="storage/logs/*.log
```

Then, I upload the tar archive on the production server, and launch on the server this sequence of commands (with sudo or as root):

```
# deleting the content of the project directory
rm -R /var/www/MYPROJECT/{*,.*}

# unpacking the tar I've just uploaded
tar -xf /somewhere/MYARCHIVE-VERSION.tar.gz /var/www/MYPROJECT/

# down of app and executing the migration
php artisan down
php artisan migrate

# recreating the log file to avoid some permission errors
touch /var/www/MYPROJECT/storage/logs/laravel.log

# changing permissions of various files
chmod -R 777 /var/www/MYPROJECT/storage /var/www/MYPROJECT/bootstrap/cache
chown -R www-data:www:data /var/www/MYPROJECT/{*,.*}

# generating the app key, if is the first deploy (actually, this is my case: in the .env file the APP_KEY is empty)
php artisan key:generate

# cleaning config, cache, etc, etc
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan auth:clear-resets
php artisan optimize

# restart app and webserver
php artisan up
systemctl restart apache2
```

Ok, when I restart apache, I have ALWAYS the error: INVALID ROUTE ACTION for EVER route I call, for example the /dashboard:

```
Invalid route action: [C:32:"Opis\Closure\SerializableClosure":210:{a:5:{s:3:"use";a:0:{}s:8:"function";s:44:"function () { return \view('dashboard'); }";s:5:"scope";s:37:"Illuminate\Routing\RouteFileRegistrar";s:4:"this";N;s:4:"self";s:32:"0000000049110cda00000000033dff1d";}}].
```

I guess the problem is in the cache or in the key: **after some attemps the applications works**. For example if I re-generate the app key and then re-optimize with `php artisan optmize` twice, the app actually works!

Where is the errors?

Appreciate any tips, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a closure in some of your routes.

When you call `php artisan optimize`, `$this->call('route:cache');` will be executed and your routes will be loaded from a cached file. That could explain why it resolves your issue.

Make sure to call `php artisan route:cache` after each deployment, or move the closures in your route definitions to controllers.

Comment: I've just tried, it doesn't works, error is the same: after the optimizazion and the route caching, I have to re-generate key and re-launch optimize otherwise the application got the same error...

Comment: Ok, other clue: if i do not generate application key, that is, if I use a .env with APP_KEY already configured, the deploy works like a charms. Maybe my problem appears only for the FIRST deploy...